# Javascript Background toggle on Popup

Tags: javascript

I have a div assigned to trigger some Javascipt which opens a 'PopUp' RSVP form on my site,I however also want to have a black background full screen overlay when the window pops up to hide the rest of the site.

The popup window works fine using this:

```
$(function() {
    // contact form animations
    $('#contact').click(function() {
    $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $("#contactForm");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the      container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.fadeOut();
    }
});
```

So I want to attach the overlay action into this function so that it toggles on and off with the PopUpWindow. I already have a div assigned with the correct CSS,I just need to get it to also toggle:

```
.sidebar-overlay {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
    cursor: e-resize;
}
```

I am a little stuck so any help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think in your script, you checked for the contact form being clicked or not, but then you hide only the form, and not the sidebar-overlay section. So it's really just a slight mix up in which selector is in use. (I can't be positive if that's what's going on, as you did not include the html markup in your question.)

Here's a quick example with your code and the matching html. Only, the sidebar-overlay is hid on click of the document area.

```js
  $('#contact').click(function() {
    var container = $(".sidebar-overlay");
    container.fadeToggle();
  });
  
  $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    
    var container = $(".sidebar-overlay");
    var contactform = $("#contactForm");

    if (!contactform.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the      container...
        && contactform.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        container.fadeOut();
    }
  });
```

```css
.sidebar-overlay {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 3;
  display: none;
  cursor: e-resize;
}
#contactForm{
  width:50%;
  margin:20px auto;
  padding:20px;
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="contact">click</button>

<div class="sidebar-overlay">

<form id="contactForm">
This is my form<br />
field 1 ______<br />
field 2 ______<br />
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou for this, but wierdly although the code works perfectly when trying it on the 'run code snippit' on here it does absolutly nothing on my site...I have no idea why

Comment: If you wanted, maybe you can provide your entire page's html and script, so there would be more info to look at.From what you explained, I'm sure there's a simple fix.